# Travis-CI fails to install composer deps

Tags: php, composer-php, travis-ci

Travis-CI start to fail on installing composer deps with next error:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]                                      
Package ext-ssh2-0.12.0.0 must have a source or dist specified
```

https://travis-ci.org/deployphp/deployer/jobs/62059967

Here is [composer.json](https://github.com/deployphp/deployer/blob/master/composer.json). Locally everything good.

Why Travis-CI fails?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Composer is unable to install php extensions yet.

It looks like you need to provide source for "ext-ssh2", see [this issue](https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider/issues/215).

```
{
    "repositories":[
        {
            "type":"package",
            "package": {
                "name":"bower-asset/seiyria-bootstrap-slider",
                "version":"3.1.0",
                "dist": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider/archive/3.1.0.zip",
                    "type": "zip"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: But i do not require `ext-ssh2`.

Comment: It was required by some of your dependencies and source was missing in it. Looks like your [Travis is fine now](https://travis-ci.org/deployphp/deployer/jobs/62188499). What was the solution?

Comment: Travis-CI disabled ext-ssh2, one of packages was requiring  ext-ssh2, but composer shows strange error. Now removed this package. Thanks you!